# Slow SQL query when almost no data

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, optimization

I have a fairly complicated SQL query that I'm running against Postgres 14. It runs fine in production with a few thousands rows and takes about 200 ms.

The same query on my development server with less than 10 rows takes 7 seconds!

Production hardware is nothing special - an AWS T3 medium. In development, it's a Virtualbox VM running on a Intel 9900k.

Other queries are roughly equivalent in performance between dev & prod.

The SQL query joins a few tables and views like this:

```sql
    SELECT product.*, track_view.*, release_view.* user.*
    FROM product
    LEFT JOIN track_view ON product.id = track_view.digital_product_id
    LEFT JOIN user ON user.id = COALESCE(track_view.user_id, release_view.seller_id);
```

The track_view and release_view have additional joins to other tables and do some json aggregation.

This is the bottom end of the explain analyse outputs run against each database.

[image: Production explain Analyse]

[image: Development explain analyse]

I'm not familiar that familiar with explain output but it looks like 5s was optimisation and 2.5s was emission.

How should I approach improving it?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) **Do not use images** for textual data. Copy and paste as text into your question text. 2) Did you run `ANALYZE` on the tables in the dev database?

Comment: Does this actually run? release_view is not in any "FROM" clause, just there as a join predicate, so maybe it's doing some absurd cartesian product?

Comment: Please include the plan in TEXT form, not images, so we can look at it.

Comment: You didn't share the entire query plan, and it's not readable anyway: Use plain text. And since you're using a view, we need the underlying SQL for this view as well, and the DDL for all tables and indexes involved. Could you share the result from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for your SQL statement? (it looks like JIT doesn't work well in your case)

Comment: At a guess, your test environment is missing indexes, is starting the database cold, or has bad statistics causing a large memory grant request for the query.

Comment: JIT Optimization 4936.386 ms, Emission 2758.771 ms,Total 7794.198 ms. This time is included to your 7 second?

Comment: @ValNik Yes, that total 7794 milliseconds is part of the 7805 milliseconds. That's why I pointed to JIT. Something goes wrong in the planning, not the in the execution of the query.

Comment: I think, time spending not with query, but in used ORM or higher. On ``product side`` all this generation, optimisation, (assembling) already been done.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver sorry I coudn't figure out at the time how to copy the text from pgAdmin so took a screenshot. It's also 193 lines long so thought pasting the whole plan might make be a bit long.

I've run analyse now and that has fixed it - the same query is now taking 48ms. Are you able to explain what would cause it to spend 5-7seconds extra before running analyse? Does it get stuck in some kind of loop trying to find the best query plan?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn thanks for those tips. The indexes should be the same as the DDL is created automatically from schema using Prisma migrate. The other 2 are likely. It seems that running analyse has fixed the issue. Same query now takes 43ms. Does this lend itself to point 3 - bad stats/large memory?

Comment: @FrankHeikens That statement gave a syntax error at char 45. However, running analyse has fixed the issue.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver maybe you would like to add Analyse as an answer with explanation what might have caused it to require it and I can select it.

Comment: @ValNik The problem was experienced using pgadmin and direct nodejs pg library. It seems that running ANALYSE has fixed it so it was something to do with the database.

Comment: My be, if there was a massive deletion of data from the test database.

Comment: @ValNik, It also happens on a freshly created test db with no data.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/populate.html#POPULATE-ANALYZE

> 14.4.8. Run ANALYZE Afterwards

> Whenever you have significantly altered the distribution of data within a table, running ANALYZE is strongly recommended. This includes bulk loading large amounts of data into the table. Running ANALYZE (or VACUUM ANALYZE) ensures that the planner has up-to-date statistics about the table. With no statistics or obsolete statistics, the planner might make poor decisions during query planning, leading to poor performance on any tables with inaccurate or nonexistent statistics. Note that if the autovacuum daemon is enabled, it might run ANALYZE automatically; see Section 25.1.3 and Section 25.1.6 for more information.

For information on where those statistics are stored and for what purpose see:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-statistic.html

For more detail on the planner and how it works with the statistics see:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/performance-tips.html